# Airflow 2.0.2 - SnowflakeHook can't read query located in directory

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we're moving to airflow 2.0 and I noticed the below error, it seems SnowflakeHook can't read the query located in our 'sql' directory, this was running fine in airflow 1.x:

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 001003 (42000):
> 019c5ac7-0602-31b5-0000-01b526e4fa46: SQL compilation error: syntax
> error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'sql'.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> common.snowflake.exceptions.SQLCompilationSnowflakeException:  001003
> (42000): 019c5ac7-0602-31b5-0000-01b526e4fa46: SQL compilation error:
> syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'sql'. Error occured
> while processing query(019c5ac7-0602-31b5-0000-01b526e4fa46):
> sql/my_query.sql

Below is the class we've created:

```
class SnowQueryOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ['sql']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 sql,
                 params=None,
                 warehouse=Variable.get('default_snowflake_warehouse'),
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sql = sql
        self.params = params
        self.warehouse = warehouse

    def execute(self, context):
        sf_hook = SnowflakeHook(warehouse=self.warehouse)
        sf_hook.execute_query(self.sql)
```

and this is how we use it:

```
t4 = SnowQueryOperator(
    task_id='running_snowflake_query',
    sql='sql/my_query.sql',
    retries=0,
    pool='airflow')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this code worked on Airflow 1.10
you are missing `template_ext` that will allow you to read from `.sql` files.

```
class SnowQueryOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('sql')
    template_ext = ('.sql',)
```

I'm not clear on why you implemented this operator on your own. Airflow has [Snowflake provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-snowflake/) which has [SnowflakeOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/858f93cb79384c1034f3fa081bb0cc246582db94/airflow/providers/snowflake/operators/snowflake.py#L24).

You can install it with `pip install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake` and then import the operator as `from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator`

Comment: thank you for responding! Someone had created this class a while ago, but I'll bring it up if we can use the build in SnowflakeOperator instead, also this worked!